# Sparkml predicting with new data gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have trained and saved a model and now I am trying to use this model to prediction using new data. I've tried many things and always the erros is the same as presented below.

Just to let you know I've tried creating manually a dataframe and also I've tried to create manually the features Vectors and didn’t work.

I am using the same pipeline that was used when I've create the model as well. I couldn't imagine that this simple thing would be so painful using spark.

**Spark Version: 2.4.4** and I am using **Python** in this case.

Please help me!

**Loading the model and pedicting:**

```
gbt_model_load  = GBTRegressionModel.load('gbt_model/')
gbt_model_pred  = gbt_model_load.transform(dfFeat1)
gbt_model_pred.printSchema()
gbt_model_pred.select('budgetvalue','prediction').show()
```

**Error:**

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o8585.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 589.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 589.0 (TID 2134, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$3: (struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>) => double)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1226
    at org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector.apply(Vectors.scala:462)
```

**Code Details:**

```
data_df = spark.read.csv('abt/data/*',header=True, inferSchema=True)

def featuresCreation(df):
    continuous_cols  = ['a','b','c']
    categorical_cols = ['d','e']

    categorical_indexers = [
        StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol="{0}_indexed".format(column), handleInvalid='keep')
        for column in categorical_cols
]

    categorical_features = [
        OneHotEncoder(
            inputCol=indexer.getOutputCol(),
            outputCol="{0}_encoded".format(indexer.getOutputCol()))
         for indexer in categorical_indexers
    ]

    continuous_feature = [VectorAssembler(
        inputCols=[column for column in continuous_cols],
        outputCol="continuous_features"
   )]

    continuous_feature_standard = [StandardScaler(inputCol='continuous_features', outputCol='scaled_continuous_features')]

    all_features = continuous_feature_standard + categorical_features

    universal_assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=[feature.getOutputCol() for feature in all_features],
    outputCol="features"
    )

    estimator = categorical_indexers + \
                categorical_features + \
                continuous_feature + \
                continuous_feature_standard + \
                [universal_assembler]

    universal_pipeline = Pipeline(stages=estimator)
    #universal_pipeline.save('universal_pipeline/')
    data_features_df   = universal_pipeline.fit(df).transform(df)

    return data_features_df
```

**Applying pipeline:**

```
data_features_df = featuresCreation(data_df)
```

**Training the model:**

```
gbt           = GBTRegressor(featuresCol='features',labelCol='budgetvalue', maxDepth=3, maxIter=40)
gbt_model     = gbt.fit(train_df)
gbt_pred      = gbt_model.transform(test_df)
gbt_evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(labelCol='budgetvalue', predictionCol='prediction', metricName='rmse')
gbt_rmse      = gbt_evaluator.evaluate(gbt_pred)
```

Comment: Make sure you have the same number of features as what the model was trained on. Spark is complaining about out-of-bounds vector access, which points to mismatched vector lengths.

Comment: I did a test with the some rows with the data that I've used to train and test the model just to evaluate where could possibly be the error, but for my surprise same error happened.

Comment: @MLins: The error should be due to different vector lengths for the features. Can you add all relevant code here (training/testing)? Also see: [mcve]

Comment: @Shaido-ReinstateMonica, thank you. I've just updated with some more details.

Comment: @Shaido-ReinstateMonica.But I think you are right. The scenario is that I am training and saving the model, but when I try to use it to predict (for a new row for example) I am using the same pipeline for transform and create the features and as you said seems that this Vector is different. I am trying to find out why